# One problem to cover all the time complexities

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, big-o, complexity-theory

A college instructor here. I am trying to find a meaningful (practical) code example to illustrate different time complexities for beginners in a ELi5 manner. The code should start with constant complexity and then incrementally, by adding small piece of code, increases in complexity: .., logn, n, nlogn, n^2, 2^n, ..

I think I can explain it better with one example that has small incremental changes rather than switch the context from searching to sorting to brute force algorithms .

Comment: There are uncountably many `O` classes, so *cover all* is impossible. I suggest to reframe the question as *cover common*.

Answer (score 2):

Any example will be artificial.  But here is one that does reasonably well.

Let `vec` be a sorted array of numbers, `i` an integer, and `x` be another number.  In order answer the following questions.

1. `O(1)` What is the value of `vec[i]`?
2. `O(n)` Is `x` in a range from `vec` by linear search?
3. `O(log(n))` Is `x` in a range from `vec` by binary search?
4. `O(n^2)` Is `x` the sum of two elements in a range from of `vec` by a double loop?
5. `O(n log(n))` Is `x` the sum of two elements of `vec` by linear search on the first with a binary search on the second.  (Simplifying trick, do a linear search on the smaller and binary on the second. then reuse your code from 3.)
6. `O(2^n)` Is `x` the sum of any subset of elements of `vec` by recursion?
7. (pseudopolynomial) Memoize the previous solution.  Discuss memory vs speed tradeoffs.